# Calculate the radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, radicals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

How to calculate the radical of the ideal $\langle zw^3,xyzw,x^5y^6\rangle$ in $k[x,y,z,w]$?

I know that the radical is the intersection of all minimal prime ideals. Then I considered a minimal prime ideal and find the possibilities $\langle y,w\rangle$, $\langle y,z\rangle$, $\langle x,w\rangle$ and $\langle x,z\rangle$.

I can not develop more than that.
I accept suggestions. Thx.

Comment: To compute the radical of a monomial ideal, just cut down all exponents and then (if necessary) throw away redundant generators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right path. $\langle y,w\rangle\cap\langle y,z\rangle=\langle y,wz\rangle$ and $\langle x,w\rangle\cap\langle x,z\rangle=\langle x,wz\rangle$, so the answer you are looking for is $\langle y,wz\rangle\cap\langle x, wz\rangle=\langle yx,wz\rangle$.