# Calculating Radical of an Ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Can someone explain how to calculate the radical of the ideal $(x^3,xy^5)?$ I'm not sure how to calculate this.

Comment: As a hint, take the ideal $(x^2)$. Then it's radical is the ideal $(x)$. Similarly, the radical of $(x^5)$=$(x^2)$=$(x)$. You could intuitively think of it as "going back to the base of the ideal." (So maybe notice that the radical of $(x^3)$ is $(x)$).

Comment: See this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2352204/calculate-the-radical

Comment: It should be clarified what ring has the ideal $(x^3, xy^5)$.  Readers should not have to guess in order to respond.

Answer (score 1):

For $I = (x^3, xy^5)$ (say in $k[x,y]$ for some field $k$), you want to calculate the radical $\sqrt{I}$ defined by
$$\sqrt{I} = \{a \in k[x,y]: a^n \in I \text{ for some $n$}\}$$
We claim that $\sqrt{I} = (x)$.

- On one hand, $(x) \subset \sqrt{I}$ since $x^3 \in I$.
- On the other hand, if $a^n \in I$, clearly $a^n$ is a multiple of $x$. But as $x$ is a prime element in $k[x,y]$, we see that $a$ is already a multiple of $x$, i.e. $\sqrt{I} \subset (x)$.